# How to stretch width layout in xml to fill screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've got an app I'm working on that I inherited. I'm trying to make it so the box in the image provided below labeled "RelativeLayout" stretches all the way to edge of the screen horizontally, so that there's no white space in between it and the screen. Any way to do that? I've tried "match_parent" and "wrap_content" but neither of those do the trick

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je5u0.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout           
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/view_cont"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#406490">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leg_name"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leg_office"
            android:layout_width="207dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="President of the United States Amercia"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leg_photo"
            android:layout_width="127dp"
            android:layout_height="121dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/leg_name"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-47dp"
            card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/icon1" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is happening because you added a margin of 1dp to your parent CardView. Also because `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding` is set to TRUE

Try the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/view_cont"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#406490">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/leg_name"
                android:layout_width="207dp"
                android:layout_height="44dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Name"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/leg_office"
                android:layout_width="207dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="President of the United States Amercia"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/leg_photo"
                android:layout_width="127dp"
                android:layout_height="121dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/leg_name"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-47dp"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_directions_walk_black_24dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works, good luck!